# Validation for items in ObservableCollection bound to DataGrid when validation of one item of collection depends on other items

Tags: validation, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

I am using MVVM and displaying some items on a DataGrid.  My model is RecordingInfo and looks like:

```
public class RecordingInfo : IDataErrorInfo
{

    public RecordingInfo(string fullDirectoryName, string recordingName, int recordingNumber)
    {
        FullDirectoryName = fullDirectoryName;
        RecordingName = recordingName;
        RecordingNumber = recordingNumber;

    }
    public string FullDirectoryName { get; internal set; }
    public string RecordingName { get;  set; }
    public int RecordingNumber { get; internal set; }


    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get {
            if (propertyName == "RecordingName")
            {
                if (this.RecordingName.Length < 2)
                    return "Recording Name must be at least two characters";
            }
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

I end up with a collection of these RecordingInfo programmatically.  The user is not allowed to do much with these but he/she can change the RecordingName subject to the name being 2 characters or more AND that the RecordingName must be unique. I.e. no changing it to match another RecordingName. I have taken care of the first requirement.  It's the second one that is giving me grief.

For my ViewModel, I have

```
public class RecordingListViewModel : ViewModelBase//, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private ObservableCollection<RecordingInfo> _recordings = null;



    public RecordingListViewModel()
    {

    }
    public ObservableCollection<RecordingInfo> Recordings
    {
        get
        {
            return _recordings;
        }
    }
    // more stuff left off for brevity
```

In my view I bind the collection to a DataGrid and have:

```
<DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Recordings}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Recording"  IsReadOnly="False"   EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CellEditStyle}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource CellNonEditStyle}" Binding="{Binding RecordingName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" >

                </DataGridTextColumn>
                ...
            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

My way of checking for 2 or more characters works great.  But this doesn't work for checking that the user is not trying to give a recording an existing name.  Presumably, I need to somehow handle this at the ViewModel layer since the ViewModel knows about all Recordings.   I tried playing with having my ViewModel derive from IDataErrorInfo but the property indexer never gets called, which makes sense as it's the Observable collection and therefore the individual RecordingInfos that are bound.  I also thought about doing something with a "Lost Focus" event, but DataGridTextColumn doesn't seem to have that.  I would think this is a somewhat common problem: validation must take into account relationships between the items of the collection.

By the way, I'm not wedded to the IDataErrorInfo and I am not opposed to other changes in architecture.  Please let me know if I can provide more details.  I have tried to provide a minimal amount of code.  Clearly, this is part of a much bigger project.  Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following
1) Make RecordingInfo implement INotifyPropertyChanged
2) Use a BindingList<> instead of ObservableCollection<>

In your viewmodel, subscribe to the BindingList.ListChanged Event. This event will fire when items are added and removed, but also when the top level properties on RecordingInfo changes. In the case of a property being changed, the ListChangedEventArgs.PropertyDescriptor property will contain the name of the property, if you want to run validation for just that property (be careful though, this can be null when the item as added/removed). You'll need to use the ListChangedType property to determine the reason of the event (E.x.: Reset means everything changed, ItemAdded means the item was added, but the ItemChanged means a property changed as occurred on an existing item.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the parent ViewModel (that contains and creates your RecordingInfos) pass a name validation Func in their constructors for them to call when validating their name changes.